# OSX shows warning that application was downloaded from the internet, any way to stop this?

Tags: macos, high-sierra

Im running OSX 10.13 and my preferred browser is Google Chrome, i have set this as my default browser.

Every time i open Chrome i get the following alert (see screenshot) is this normal ? And can i set it to remember my answer so it doesn't keep asking me ?

[image: screenshot of confirmation window shown when opening chrome in OSX]